# Is it possible to change the IP in sending Curl the request?

Tags: bash, terminal, curl, macos

I'm using this code to change the IP address

```
curl --header "X-Forwarded-for: $((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256)).$((RANDOM % 256))" 'www.example.com'
```

In fact, the target site does not accept this IP change. Is it possible to change the IP address?

Comment: X-Forwarded-For does absolutely nothing to your IP address, it tells the server that you are a proxy (or pretending to be) and sends the IP address of the client (not yours).

Comment: @OskarSkog Is there no way?

Comment: You would have to change the IP address of your machine.